# Cryptocompare API is not updated

Tags: api, trading, buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate, raw-data

I have created an android app for maintaining the portfolio. I have used the coinmarketcap.com API. This API does not have the data at exchange level.

I have tried https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/ this does not have the exchanges like some of the exchanges like https://koinex.in (or) Zebpay.com and the some crypto pairs.These are just some of the missing exchanges.

Is there is any API which has all the exchanges in the crypto world ?

I wonder how other apps are fetching all the possible exchanges and the crypto currency pairs. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

These aggregating sites are just hooking up to every exchange API and querying the data and then dumping it in a database. You could do the same, it's a decent amount of work and costs money to run the server.

For example, Coinigy's API is hooked up with just about every exchange and pair, it is a paid service. I have no affiliation with them. This is only an example.

Comment: Ohh, that's a cost to my project :( .. Any other way apart from running a server ?